# Display report in visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, report, visualforce, apex

i want to display a report on a visualforce page. I found this snippet of code but it brings back a blank page. What piece am i missing to have it show the report data?

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <apex:iframe src="/00OQ0000000Gdbm"/>  
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is 00OQ0000000Gdbm a valid Report Id in your Salesforce Org? What happens in you just append that to the base Salesforce URL?

Comment: yeah it is a valid report ID.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use code that looks like this to show a report in a Visualforce page.  I've left out details that would get in the way:

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomOb__c"  extensions="CobjController">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Manage Stuff"/> 
<apex:form> 
...

<apex:outputPanel id="MissingAttRpt" >
<apex:iframe src="/00O0000000AAJlV?isdtp=lt" scrolling="true"  height="1588px"  width="100%"/>   
</apex:outputPanel>

...
</apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

The outputPanel is used so that the report can be re-rendered without refreshing the whole page.

Try getting rid of the showHeader and sidebar properties.

Comment: I assure you that it is currently working for me.  I just checked.  Instead of downvoting with no additional detail, you could consider opening a question.